# Uses of UML in object oriented analysis and design

Tags: uml, software-design, ooad

this question is regarding Object Oriented Analysis and design ,UML

**in object oriented analysis final result is the class diagramme of system am i right?**

**in object oriented design final result is implement the class diagramme in code am i right ?**

**what is the use of UML diagramms in OOAD?**

---

- in object oriented analysis i have seen use these UML diagrams - use case diagram,sequence diagram to create the class diagram
- are above diagrams are the only ones that used in analysis(create the class diagramme)?

---

- in object oriented design i have seen used these UML  diagrams - class diagram , sequential diagram to used to implement the code(code of the classes)
- are above diagrams are the only ones that used in design to implement class diagram in code?

---

- or depending on need other type of UML diagrams are use in object oriented analysis and object oriented design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**in object oriented analysis final result is the class diagramme of system am i right?**
No. The result of the analysis is a model that represents the problem domain. Any diagram used is just a means to reflect the model to its readers.

**in object oriented design final result is implement the class diagramme in code am i right ?**
No. The result is an architectural model which is based on the analysis model. You might be able to generate code from this model. At least a coder can take this model to transform it to code.

**what is the use of UML diagramms in OOAD?**
UML diagrams are used to visualize the model of the problem domain. You can live without the diagrams, but they support communication between humans.

You will use different diagram types depending on what part(s) of the model you will shed light on.

Comment: Take a good book about UML and some time to read it. Once you have specific questions, come back.

Answer (score 3):

**UML is the toolbox used by OOAD to express the different design phases in a *common and understandable language*.**

Has you know the 3 main phases of the OOAD involve different kind of UML diagrams

- **Object-oriented Analysis (OOA)**: Use cases and object models ( class diagram, package diagram).
- **Object-oriented Design (OOD)**: Software architecture using design patterns and architectural patterns ... expressed using UML.
- **Object-oriented Modeling (OOM)**: used by OOD and OOA. It is separated in two types of analysis:

  - Structural diagrams: static representation diagrams use cases, packages and classes diagrams
  - Behavioral diagrams using dynamic diagrams like sequence diagram, collaboration diagram etc.

> **Object-oriented modeling (OOM)** is a common approach to modeling
>   applications, systems, and business domains by using the
>   object-oriented paradigm throughout the entire development life
>   cycles. **OOM is a main technique heavily used by both OOA and OOD**
>   activities in modern software engineering.

See the dedicated [Wikipedia page for details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_analysis_and_design).